# How to create deeplink for UPI payment via website

Tags: payment-gateway, deep-linking, upi

I am trying to integrate UPI payment option in website but didn't found much information online. Can anyone suggest how to generate deep linking via website and get the notification of the payment in my website.

Answer (score 1):

Deep linking for UPI payment is possible only in mobile applications. [This](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf) is the documentation by NPCI.

If you want to use UPI payment in your website, you can use [Google Pay SDK](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/) (Only for Google Pay).